# Failed to connect to containerd: failed to dial

Tags: linux, docker, containerd

Just installed Docker CE following official instructions with the repository in Ubuntu 14.04

Installation went successfully, the daemon is running

```
$ ps aux | grep docker
[...] /usr/bin/dockerd --raw-logs [...]
```

My user is in the docker group:

```
$ groups
[...] docker
```

The cli can't seem to communicate (same with sudo)

```
$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock.
Is the docker daemon running?
```

The socket seems to have the correct permissions:

```
$ ls -l /var/run/docker.sock
srw-rw---- 1 root docker 0 Feb  4 16:21 /var/run/docker.sock
```

The log seems to claim about some issues though

```
$ sudo tail -f /var/log/upstart/docker.log
```

> Failed to connect to containerd: failed to dial "/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock": dial unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout
>   /var/run/docker.sock is up
>   time="2018-02-04T16:22:21.031459040+01:00" level=info msg="libcontainerd: started new docker-containerd process" pid=17147
>   INFO[0000] starting containerd                           module=containerd revision=89623f28b87a6004d4b785663257362d1658a729 version=v1.0.0
>   INFO[0000] setting subreaper...                          module=containerd
>   containerd: invalid argument
>   time="2018-02-04T16:22:21.056685023+01:00" level=error msg="containerd did not exit successfully" error="exit status 1" module=libcontainerd

Any advice to make this work ?

---

*Relog and Docker restart already done of course*

Answer (score 1):

Same situation happend on me. IS because your linux kernel version too low !!! check it use command "uname -r" , if the version below "3.10" (for example:  debian 7 whezzy default version is 3.2 ) ,even you install docker-ce suceessfully, you will still can not start docker daemon success.That why! All most answers on the web tell you to 'restart' bla bla bla... but they did not consider this problem.

Comment: That is correct, I had a 3.2 kernel. After having upgraded it to 3.19 it worked fine

Answer (score 1):

As @bobbear suggested and is actually [mentioned in the official doc](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#prerequisites) one of the prerequisites is:

> Version 3.10 or higher of the Linux kernel. The latest version of the kernel available for you platform is recommended.

After having checked my Kernel version:

```
$ uname -a
Linux [...] 3.2.[...]-generic [...]-Ubuntu [...] x86_64
```

I searched for candidates:

```
$ apt-cache search linux-image
```

And installed my `new_kernel`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install \
    linux-image-new_kernel \
    linux-headers-new_kernel \
    linux-image-extra-new_kernel
```