# Cannot start docker daemon, failed to connect do containerd

Tags: docker, daemon

I get an error when trying to start docker daemon, I get the following error

> Failed to connect to containerd: failed to dial
>   "/var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock": dial
>   unix:///var/run/docker/containerd/docker-containerd.sock: timeout

I have no idea of what might be causing this error.

My Docker version is 17.12.0-ce, and I'm using Ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which version of docker you are using, on which host (Linux, which OS, type `uname -a`)

See for instance [`docker/for-linux` issue 218](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/218)

> What kernel version are you running (uname -a) ?
>
> ```
>  3.2.0-33-generic
> ```
>
> That's the issue. https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/binaries/
>
> Version 3.10 or higher of the Linux kernel.

That being said, [`docker/for-linux` issue 274](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/274) reports the same problem... but with a kernel up-to-date.

Comment: Sorry, I have added this information
My Docker version is 17.12.0-ce, and I'm using Ubuntu 17.04

Comment: @JuanDavidPorrasPalencia yes, but which kernel? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48619280/6309

Comment: After running the command it says: Linux <machine-name> 4.10.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 14:38:01 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: @JuanDavidPorrasPalencia Can you try: complete uninstall of docker, then re-install, but with https://www.docker.com/docker-ubuntu en 18.03 ou, si cela ne marche pas, en edge (https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#set-up-the-repository)?